# What is the stall speed for the Dassault Rafale?

Tags: fighter, stall, rafale

Looking at this video of a Rafale escorting a high-speed train (TGV)

I was wondering what the stall speed for the Rafale is at close to sea level altitude.

Is this information generally public for fighter aircraft? I could conceive this would be classified.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but a piece of related information for readers : the commercial top speed of this train is about 300 km/h (video comment says it was going 320km/h).

Comment: Nice question! Note: with this train going to 320kph (198mph) I suppose it is far from stall speed

Comment: Lower than a train top speed, I'd guess ;-D

Comment: From [Dassault's site](https://www.dassault-aviation.com/en/defense/rafale/specifications-and-performance-data/): "*Approach speed: less than 120 knots*". If approach speed is 1.3 Vs, Vs is less than 100 kt (185 km/h). And btw this train has a speed record of [574 km/h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TGV_world_speed_record) (310 kt), a [video of the record](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOdATLzRGHc) on YT. Stall speed has to be understood as speed where CLmax is reached in unaccelerated straight and level flight.

Comment: @mins to be more precise, this **train class** has a speed record of 574 km/h, but this was on a [special project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_V150_%28High_Speed_Train%29_-_France).

Comment: Your question is unclear. What stall speed are you asking for? Clean configuration? Landing configuration? Wings level or banked? Load factor of 1.0 or other than 1.0? Stall speed varies greatly. Conversely, AoA is constant for a given configuration.

Comment: @le_daim: Interesting article. It's generally well understood the wheels were larger and the track is descending, as it was the case near Vendôme for the previous record. By the way the plane mentioned in the article is a [Corvette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%A9rospatiale_Corvette) with a stall speed of 91 kt (168 km/h).

Comment: I guess the ideal answer would have a table of stall speed by configuration/weight/height ? At minima, it would be "what is the lowest speed achievable in level flight for any configuration and realistic amounts of fuel (1h or more left).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

80 knots for an aggressive pilot, as said [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131017084238/http://www.defencenews.in/defence-news-internal.asp?get=new&id=323).

It is 148 km/h, a speed of fast but rather typical long range passenger train. No new technology is required for the train, this plane could easily follow a Pacific steam locomotive (top speed [203 km/h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-6-2#Overview)).

Comment: It must be said that in airshows the airplane flies almost empty - no munitions, no external loads (even the missiles can be dummies) and little fuel in the tanks. With only 10t empty weight, it reaches those 80 knots at half the wing loading of a fully loaded plane. This would make the "real" stall speed closer to 113 knots.